# Question regarding simple Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have been teaching myself some Javascript; and I am having trouble getting this function to run properly. 
This is what is being output.

Answer: [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var firstNum = document.getElementById("num1");
  var secondNum = document.getElementById("num2");
  result = firstNum + secondNum;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Answer: " + result;
  return result;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--            ,<script src="scripts.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

  <p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation and returns the result:</p>


  <form>
    First Number<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstNum" id="num1"><br> Second Number<br>
    <input type="text" name="secondNum" id="num2"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Add!" onclick="addNumbers()">
  </form>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're logging the input elements themselves, instead of their values.  Try e.g. `var firstNum = document.getElementById("num1").value`

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns a node. If you want the content of it, you'll need to extract the value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. With `document.getElementById("num2")` you are selecting the element with id `num2` and not it's value.

Comment: (Also, you'll need to convert those values into numbers before adding them together --  `Number(firstNum) + Number(secondNum)`

Comment: That did it thanks! and also for the values conversion bit, Would have stumbled me next for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the comments said, get the value from the HTML element node and parse it into a float

```
var firstNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var secondNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
```

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var firstNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var secondNum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  result = firstNum + secondNum;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Answer: " + result;
  return result;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--            ,<script src="scripts.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

  <p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation and returns the result:</p>


  <form>
    First Number<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstNum" id="num1"><br> Second Number<br>
    <input type="text" name="secondNum" id="num2"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Add!" onclick="addNumbers()">
  </form>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```